# chromium doesn't load some web pages

Tags: 14.04, networking, chromium

When I type in 192.168.8.1 (My Wi-Fi router home page) into URL bar of chromium  the page doesn't load and the loading circle goes back and forth. The page loads fine in Firefox.

- Chromium version 50.0.2661.102
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474010/why-cant-i-get-to-my-routers-admin-settings-using-google-chrome-browser

Comment: @ digiwizkid , I tried the suggested answer. like that still I can't open in New tabs (ie, Ordinary) But it works fine in Incognito Window. !!!! ??? What about next step

Comment: Please refer https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8An6FHiQdg8 for more detailed and let me know

Comment: @digiwizkid , Sorry I can't understand it, Is it for Ubuntu ???                        ` IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.8.101
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.8.1

    DNS:             192.168.8.1`